# Installing VIM command as a plugin

Tags: vim

I have the following command run as a vim plugin under ~/.vim/plugin/autohighlight.vim

`:autocmd CursorMoved * exe printf('match IncSearch /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))`

The thing is, it throws a bunch of errors anywhere except when I'm editing a file. (file Explorer, other windows)

Is there a way to tell the script to only take effect when a file is edited and not anywhere else in VIM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * :if filewritable(@%)==1 |
                      \    call matchadd('IncSearch', '\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>').'\>', '\'), 10, 1) |
                      \endif
```

It will do highlighting only if current buffer name is a writable file (not directory). It will fail if you are editing something which uses `BufWriteCmd` to perform saving (for example, if you are editing file inside a zip archive).

By the way, can you provide these errors? I was able to get an error when I used `:e .`, but it was not related to the fact that you are observing a directory, it appeared just because you **forgot to do escaping**. If you have written `escape(expand('<cword>'), '\/')` instead of `expand('<cword>')` then such error would not appear.